# How can I use dynamic programming to solve an interval coverage problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**How can i use DP to solve this algorithm problem？**

Suppose we have a large interval, and in addition we have many small intervals (they all belong to this large interval).

Now select these small intervals so that they do not overlap with each other, and the areas without coverage cannot be placed in other small intervals.

Now I want to ask them to cover the minimum value of this large area

First enter the length of the large interval (starting from 1), then enter the number of small intervals, and then enter the left and right endpoints of the small intervals.

Here is an example:

16 6

1 3

1 7

4 15

8 13

8 9

11 16

output:

4

Explanation: We choose 1-7, 8-13. At this point the uncovered length is 4.

I think it looks like the classic KNAPSACK problem, but i could not solve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Let me make sure I understand the question:

**Given an interval [1, x] and n segments with endpoints a, b such that 1 <= a, b <= x, determine the minimal amount of uncovered area on the interval possible after selecting any set of non-intersecting segments.**

Given your example, why not pick the intervals [1, 3] and [4, 15], leaving an uncovered area of just one?